# How to Remove / Disable local map in charles proxy

Tags: debugging, proxy, fiddler, charles-proxy

How do I Remove / Disable local map in charles proxy?

I can see that you can disable it when you go to the "Tools" section but how do I remove the file mapping completely?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

If you want to stop using a Local map go to the "Tools > Map Local..." menu.

Then you will see a list of all local maps that are active, you can then remove or temporarily disable a local mapping.

Hope this helps

Comment: jesus, what a pain in the ass to find that setting. You'd think they would have that as a note in the site documentation.

Comment: You also would think by now they would have added the "remove" also to the Map ... dialog ...

Comment: They could have kept its a un-checkable item in the menu, or a remove in the pop up that opens thereafter !